# "This" used as return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I was testing out method chaining and found that it can be accomplished using "this" as a return type?

Here's an example:

```
class Shape {
    color: String;

    setColor(value: string): this { //Shape won't chain
        this.color = value;
        return this;
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {
    width: number;

    setWidth(value: number): Square {
        this.width = value;
        return this;
    }
}

function drawSquare(square: Square) {
    alert("width: " + square.width + "\ncolor: " + square.color);
}

let rect = new Square().setWidth(20).setColor("blue");
drawSquare(rect);
```

[Example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Shape%20%7B%0D%0A%09color%3A%20String%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09setColor(value%3A%20string)%20%3A%20this%20%7B%20%2F%2FShape%20won't%20chain%0D%0A%09%09this.color%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Square%20extends%20Shape%20%7B%0D%0A%09width%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09setWidth(value%3A%20number)%20%3A%20Square%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.width%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20drawSquare(square%3A%20Square)%20%7B%0D%0A%09alert(%22width%3A%20%22%20%2B%20square.width%20%2B%20%22%5Cncolor%3A%20%22%20%2B%20square.color)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20rect%20%3D%20new%20Square().setWidth(20).setColor(%22blue%22)%3B%0D%0AdrawSquare(rect)%3B)

Is this the correct way of achieving method chaining when mixing base and inherited classes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Surely, using polymorphic `this` makes fluent api's very easy to express as any subtypes 'flow' with the `this` type. Check the [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) section, and `F-bounded polymorphism`.